# Login to remote website

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm trying to login to [this site](http://dining.ut.ac.ir/) (now dead link). I provide my username and password (this site is not important) so that you can try it by your own, and test if it really works or not.

There are 2 problems:

1. How does this page handle CSRF? It doesn't save it on any cookie. How did it get it?
2. I use this code and it gives me HTTP 200, but it doesn't log me in. I need to login with my username and password and get the next page HTML.

   ```
   import requests
   >>> url = 'http://dining.ut.ac.ir/login'
   >>> signin = {'username' : '810192485' , 'password' : '0923122265' , '_csrf_token' : '14e993b708cbe5f8f7b356b6944bff98'}  
   >>> x = requests.post(url, data = signin)
   >>> x
   <Response [200]>
   ```

The login part of login page HTML:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="signin[_csrf_token]" value="14e993b708cbe5f8f7b356b6944bff98" id="signin__csrf_token" />         
        <table id="loginDatagrid">
        <tr>
          <td width="300"  align="left" valign="bottom"><label  style="position:relative;left:5px;bottom:5px;" for="signin_username">نام‌ کاربري (شماره دانشجویی/پرسنلی) : </label></td>
          <td width="100" align="right"  valign="bottom"><div class="loginboxdiv"><input  class="loginbox" type="text" name="signin[username]" id="signin_username" class="text" size="5" onclick='inputSelected("signin_username")'/></div>  </td>
          <td width="45"> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td width="300"  align="left"  valign="top"><label style="position:relative;left:5px;top:5px; "for="signin_password">رمز عبور (کد ملی): </label></td>
          <td width="100" align="right"  valign="top"><div class="loginboxdiv"><input class="loginbox" type="password" name="signin[password]" id="signin_password" class="text" onclick='inputSelected("signin_password")'/> </div>
          </td>
          <td width="45" align="right"  valign="top">  <input SRC="images/submit_form.jpg" type="image" value="" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form >
```

Comment: A `Login success` should normally result in a 302 HTTP code for a `redirect` once logged in.

Comment: Thanks Aron ! but still the problem remains :D ! @AronYsidoro

Comment: the page u posted gives 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not posting the fields the form expects. As you can see from the HTML, all the form fields are in Rails/PHP hash style: you need to use the same format.

```
signin = {'signin[username]' : '810192485' , 'signin[password]' : '0923122265' , 'signing[_csrf_token]' :     '14e993b708cbe5f8f7b356b6944bff98'}
```

Comment: `>>> signin {'signing[_csrf_token]': '98a38792011d13f46a228854deb43bf4', 'signin[username]': '810192485', 'signin[password]': '0923122265'}
>>> x = requests.post(url,data = signin) 
>>> x
<Response [200]>`   
this also doesn't work :(  
Does this works for you ??